# Scraping content from page encountering None type return

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am crawling company profile info from website like http://www.sfma.org.sg/member/info/a-linkz-marketing-pte-ltd

and I want the content from company name to website before category content. I have write some code, but it returns None type error.

Could anyone help to take a look at the code and see what went wrong? Many thanks.

```
import sys
import csv
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import datetime
from random import randint 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


fi = open('Input_List.csv', 'r')
#readers = list(csv.reader(fi))
readers=csv.reader(fi)
#print(readers)
df = []

for reader in readers:
    #print(str(reader)[1:-1]+"\n")
    url=str(reader)[2:-2]
    request = requests.session()
    htmlpage = requests.get(url)
    #print("status code: "+ str(htmlpage.status_code))
    if htmlpage.status_code != 200 : 
        break    # something went wrong #  
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlpage.text,'lxml')
    for result_table in soup.**findall**("div", {"class": "w3-container"}):
        #content=result_table.find('p')
        #print(result_table)
        content=result_table.text

        if(content.find("Website") > -1):
            index=content.find("Website")
            content=content[:content.find("\n",index)]
            #print(content)
            df=np.append(df,content)
            break
        #print(content)
        df=np.append(df,str(content))
        #print(df)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df)
df1.to_csv("SFMA.csv",index=False,encoding='utf-8')
        # #df.savetxt("SFMA.csv", index=False,encoding='utf-8')
# #df.save("SFMA.csv")
fi.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typo. `soup.findall("div", {"class": "w3-container"}):` should be `soup.find_all("div", {"class": "w3-container"}):`

There's no `findall` method in `BeautifulSoup`, thus it doesn't work and returns `None`.

To get the data from company name to website you can do this.

```
for result_table in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "w3-container"}):

    content=result_table.text
    index=content.find("Website")

    if(index > -1):

        content=content[:content.find("\n",index)]
        print(content)
        break
```

Comment: thank you! What a typo I made. by the way, can you kindly explain index=content.find("Website")

    if(index > -1):

Comment: @Sun `content` is a `string`. It's finding the index of the word `Website`. If the there is no such word it returns `-1`.

Comment: @ MD. Khairul Basar  sorry to bother again, I am trying to save the result in csv through Pandas, but the result file is empty with "0".Codes updated.

Comment: @Sun Code shouldn't be changed this way. It's a totally new question now. If you have difficulty with pandas post a new question.

Comment: @Sun You should change the code to previous version.

Comment: Basar, yeah thanks for remind, revert back to findall typo in code already